# As a student programmer why should I use linux

Tags: linux

Every job that I see lists they would like someone that has experience with Linux, why is that? What exactly do they want you to know that Linux can teach you?

Comment: Set-up a Linux distribution on your box and find out. Literally.

Comment: After a setup you can install some for example http server (like Apache) and configure your system, to let outside computer use this server. This should be good start (installing system, installing application, configuring firewall)

Comment: 2 years later I am now a beast at linux :-D My home install is arch and thinking about going to gentoo! I laughed at seeing this question today.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's open source.

So, you can see a code written by a professionals. :)

Comment: Most of GCC contributors are full-time professionals (but this does not mean that GCC is not messy, it is a legacy software). And most of the Linux kernel contributors are also professionals.

Answer (score 1):

To see the real -implementation of an O.S. and to learn how it works.
Linux is quite difficult to learn as compare to win and `difficulties makes man perfect.`

so go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Because a lot of servers are Linux servers.

They probably want you to know, how to use and configure such environment (configuration of Windows and configuration of Linux are two different stories).